# How to trigger the method on parent component from child using render function in Vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

How to trigger the `clicked` method on `app2` from `ComponentA` in this example.

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({});

app.component('ComponentA', {
    template: `<button @click="clicked" class='btn'>Click</button>`
});

const app2 = Vue.createApp({
   methods: {
     clicked() {
        this.clickCount += 1;
     }
   },

   render() {
     return Vue.h(app.component('ComponentA'), options);
   }
}).mount("#App");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the button click event handler try to emit an event called `clicked`, in render function define it by prefixing it by `on` and upper casing the first letter like `onClicked: (e) => {...}` inside the body of this function run `this.clicked`

```js
let options = {}
options.baseUrl = "someurl.com";

const app = Vue.createApp({})
app.component('ComponentA', {
  template: `
        <button @click="$emit('clicked')" class='btn'>Click</button>
    `
});

const app2 = Vue.createApp({
  methods: {
    clicked() {
      console.log("clicked !!!")
      this.clickCount += 1;
    }
  },
  render() {
    return Vue.h(app.component('ComponentA'), {
      onClicked: (e) => {

        this.clicked()
      }
    }, options)
  }
}).mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app" someVariable='some value'>


</div>
```

Comment: can I change the value of baseUrl when the button is clicked?

Comment: it should defined in the data option  as i suggested in the other answer